# use of 'postion: relative' with jsPlumb?

Tags: jquery, positioning, jsplumb

Firstly I am experimenting with (new to) jsPlumb. I couldn't seem to find the following in the jsPlumb documentation or by googling and am now going round in circles so it must be time to just go ahead and ask: Basically, can I relatively position elements and have them work with jsPlumb?

E.g. The following works perfectly

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html>
<head>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.23/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
   <script type='text/javascript' src="PATH/TO/jquery.jsPlumb-1.3.16-all-min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
   <div style='position: absolute; background-color: yellow; width: 100px; height: 100px' id='box1'>Box 1</div>
   <div style='position: absolute; background-color: pink; width: 100px; height: 100px' id='box2'>Box 2</div>
</body>

<script type='text/javascript'>
    jQuery(document).ready( function(){

       jsPlumb.draggable("box1");
       jsPlumb.draggable("box2");

       var e0 = jsPlumb.addEndpoint("box1", {
           endpoint:"Dot",
           anchor:"AutoDefault"
       });

       var e1 = jsPlumb.addEndpoint("box2", {
           endpoint:"Dot",
           anchor:"AutoDefault"
       });

       jsPlumb.connect({ source:e0, target:e1 });
})
</script>

</html>
```

but if I change `position: absolute` to `position: relative` for the boxes then the behaviour becomes erratic (particularly when dragging the boxes beyond the current view). Does jsPlumb require absolutely positioned elements only? What happens if I want my elements to initialise relatively positioned? Apologies if this (kind of) question has been asked or its in the documentation somewhere - but I couldn't find it.

Answer (score 0):

Your div's must be absolute positioned. Div's with relative positioned does not work with dragging [Check this](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!searchin/jsplumb/hierarchical/jsplumb/pIdJeUnuAeU/30MS7mOwYPgJ).

Comment: thanks for your info..but if the position is set to relative while dragging div's the connection line doesn't takes its correct position. You can try it out in above fiddle. Secondly, your answer doesn't make sense. There's an add comment link for every answer you can make use of that. Thanks